# Downcasting using dynamic_cast returns null

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, downcast

I'm trying to cast a base class object to a derived class object with `dynamic_cast`, but `dynamic_cast` returns null. Is it possible to downcast using `dynamic_cast`?

```
struct A {
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : A {};


int main()
{
    A* a = new A();

    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    if(b){
      std::cout << "b has value" << std::endl;
    }else{
      std::cout << "no value" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code prints out "no value".

Comment: FYI casting *down* the inheritance chain is called down casting.

Comment: You cannot get a B from an A, what would the language do if e.g. B instances had more data members than A instances?

Comment: You can't downcast `a` to `B*`, because it doesn't point to a `B`, it points to a `A`: `A` is not a `B`. You could however cast a `B*` to a `A*` because the `B*` would point to a B, which "is a" A (definition of inheritance)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because `a` is pointing to `A` in fact, not a `B`, then `dynamic_cast` will fail.

> Is it possible to downcast using `dynamic_cast`?

Yes, you can, e.g. if `a` points to `B` exactly,

```
A* a = new B;
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

> 5) If expression is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type Base, and new_type is a pointer or reference to the type Derived a run-time check is performed:
>
> a) The most derived object pointed/identified by expression is examined. If, in that object, expression points/refers to a public base of Derived, and if only one subobject of Derived type is derived from the subobject pointed/identified by expression, then the result of the cast points/refers to that Derived subobject. (This is known as a "downcast".)
>
> ...
>
> c) Otherwise, the runtime check fails. If the `dynamic_cast` is used on pointers, the null pointer value of type new_type is returned. If it was used on references, the exception [std::bad_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast) is thrown.

Comment: Am i able to use `dynamic_cast` if base object has deleted default ctor and can be created only with static function `create`?

Comment: @Herrgott Yes. `dynamic_cast` works with pointers and references, which won't involve default constructors of the base class.

Answer (score 10):

That is *per design*. dynamic_cast is used when you want to test whether a pointer to a base class object actually points to a subclass or not. If it is a subclass object, the dynamic_cast will give you a valid pointer, and if it is not, you just get a `nullptr`.

As you created a `A` class object, and and `A` is not a subclass of `B`, the dynamic_cast normally returned a null pointer.